# Appropriate UI pattern for Expandable List Item in Data table?

Tags: icons, lists, data-tables, data, accordion

I'm currently looking to find a solution for expanding a list item in a data table to display more information. One of the best solutions I've found thus far is done on reddit (see screenshot).

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO icon itself is not enough. 
 
You can use this icon, plus icon, standard chevron down icon, but also I suggest word "expand" next to it.

Also as this function is logically not connected with Comments, Share, or Save, margin right to those items needs to be at least double than margin between those items. 
 
Also it is not wrong to place that icon / function on the right hand side, vertically centered as this is standard Accordion pattern.

Comment: thank you @xul this is helpful. Agreed, icon isn't enough to describe what can be done there.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use "+" sign on right side of the data row

Comment: If you can please expand on this answer.

Comment: @mayo do you have examples on in action in popular websites?

Answer (score 0):

Using the "+" sign on the left is used in many commercial grid products like the [Shield UI grid](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/hierarchy).